# Edge swipe gesture for opening Notification Center on macOS stopped working

Tags: catalina, notifications, trackpad

Recently the edge swipe gesture for opening Notification Center stopped working on my MacBook Pro. It happened around the same time I upgraded to Catalina, but not sure if it's related. I also confirmed the setting is still enabled (screenshot below). It works fine if I click the button on the top right. Any ideas on how to resolve? Thanks.

[image: Trackpad settings]

Answer (score 7):

I managed to solve this by quitting Notification Centre using Activity Monitor.

Instructions here : https://osxdaily.com/2012/09/18/how-to-restart-notification-center-in-os-x/